# How do you submit a link to an event using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page, and on that page I create an event. Time passes, and I want to put a reminder about the event on the page using the Graph API. Manually, I can copy the URL for the event and put it in the link box, and Facebook automagically converts that and includes the event title, time, location, and image, all of which update when the event updates.

What I would like to be able to do is to use the graph API to do the same. I have tried just posting it as a link, but that doesn't seem to be converted as it does when you post the link manually. I can post a link, and somewhat mimic the look of the event post, but it won't auto-update if the event changes and doesn't quite look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to post the event's URL elsewhere on Facebook, via the API, and have it include metadata like description, picture, etc? (Which Facebook would include if the link was posted using the Facebook UI)

Could you just manually provide those parameters when making your post? (i.e post a feed story with attachments of the description, picture, link, etc

Comment: That's not what the question was asking, that bug is about being able to post a link to the event's wall. I'm talking about making a wall post on a separate page to an existing event. The title correctly describes it, but the content of the user report is not right.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now, apologies. (will edit answer)

Comment: Yes, that is a workaround and what I currently do, the problem is the event details won't update when the event changes.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, unfortunately i don't think there's any way to do this